# Can you license the same software with different licenses for different industries?

Tags: multi-licensing

If I have software that I want a non-profit or non-commercial entity to use, improve, etc. and so on, and I want them to have it open source, say GPL3, but I don't want commercial entities to be able to get it and sell it (maybe MIT non-Commercial) or make a proprietary source, can I have a license for the same software for each type of industry?

Comment: There is no such license as "MIT non-Commercial."

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Was my question not specific and clear?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

What you have in mind is [neither Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/programs-must-not-limit-freedom-to-run.html) [nor Open Source](https://opensource.org/osd) because restricting how software can be used and who can use it is against basic principles.

See also https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#NoMilitary

Comment: It’s worth pointing out here that you absolutely *can* license software this way, it just won’t meet the Free Software Foundation’s definition.

Comment: Sure. But this angel of the question is off topic here.

Comment: Dear downvoter: please tell me the reason for your downvote.

Comment: I did @LutzHorn

Comment: Please tell me why. Do you want me to edit the answer and include your comment?

Comment: I find your answer to be wrong via omission. Perhaps not wrong, but unhelpful. You’ve implied a thing can’t be done when it certainly can be done.

Comment: This site is about FLOSS, not about software in general. Asking here implies that the question is about FLOSS. In the implicit context of this site the answer to the question can only be No.

Comment: [We allow questions about the intersection of FLOSS and non-FLOSS stuff (questions about linking, dual-licensing, etc.)](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/775)

Comment: Of course we do. I did not vote to close the question as off-topic, I've answered it. But the answer is still No.

Comment: @LutzHorn I have to agree with RubberDuck here. The scope of the site may be centered around FLOSS, but we don't cut out information simply because they may or may not mention FLOSS. The issue I have with answers that cut out these sorts of information is that you start to generate incredibly specific answers that then start failing to serve the purpose of the site, which is to provide useful and genuinely helpful information. You've answered "no" - but you didn't provide the alternative which would give this answer an A+. I assume this is the main reason for RubberDuck's vote.